# JDBC - Exception. Not retrying

Tags: database, postgresql, logstash

I was trying to transfer data from one DB instance to another instance. This is my conf file

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/mysql-conf/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/write_db"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "root"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM write_db.customer_detail WHERE verificationStatus = 'VERIFIED'"
    schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
  }
}

filter {
  # Check if the address field is present in the event data.
  # If it is not present, add a default value.
 if ![id] {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "id" => "" }
  }
}
                 

  # Add any other transformations or filtering logic here if needed
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  jdbc {
    driver_jar_path => "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/postgresql-conf/postgresql-42.5.4.jar"
    driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/read_db"
    username => "postgres"
    password => "root"
    statement => "INSERT INTO read_db.customer_detail(id, phonenumber, gender, verificationstatus, address, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

  }
}
```

input works properly as data is being read. But while Inserting to another instance it throws error like

```
"2023-11-19 10:06:00 [ERROR] [jdbc]: JDBC - Exception. Not retrying {:exception=>#<Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.>, :statement=>"INSERT INTO read_db.customer_detail(id, phonenumber, gender, verificationstatus, address, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", :event=>"{\"phonenumber\":\"9\",\"id\":4,\"lastname\":\"a\",\"address\":\"a\",\"verificationstatus\":\"VERIFIED\",\"firstname\":\"a\",\"gender\":\"m\",\"@version\":\"1\",\"@timestamp\":\"2023-11-19T04:21:00.548334200Z\"}"}
```

what might be the possible solution for this ? I want my data to be transmitted to another instance.

Comment: Looks like a value for column `id`, in table `customer_detail` was not supplied for the INSERT statement. If you have a stack trace, then I suggest that you post all of it.